Problem to transmit data using FS1000A
My circuit have 4 simple parts.
Input voltage is 14.5 so I use two regulator 7805 and 7809 to power supply boards. I use 7805 for WeMos D1 mini (clone) and 7809 to supply power of FS1000A (max input voltage for this transmitter is 12).
My circuit connections are:

All GND are connected to each other.
FS1000A VCC to 7809 output.
FS1000A DATA to D7 of WeMos
WeMos VCC to 7805 output.

I cannot transmit anything with FS1000A with those connections, but When I connect FS1000A VCC to 5 V of WeMos, it works, so transmitter is healthy.
How to fix this problem? I want to use maximum power of FS1000A (I used 7809 because 7812 was unavailable in my stuff right now.)
Also, something unusual happen in my tests. I discovered FS1000A works when Vcc is disconnected from 7809 output (so there was no connection to FS1000A Vcc. Only data and GND were connected)
Main problem is still there.
Schematic here. Sorry that is kinda messed up.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Please draw a schematic.

My circuit connection is : All gnd are connected to each other. ... you have to connect more than that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@winny I'm not into this stuff much and I don't know how to draw a beautiful schematic but I will try. Thanks for you notice

@jsotola can you please be more specific? What more I need to do? Like connect 5v to 9v with one way diode in middle of it? Or what.

@Community thanks for asking it. My problem is why transmitter is not working with my regulated power supply and only works with wemos output power. Isn't data pin enough?

@jsotola I did add a diode between 5 and 9 volt (one way diode to block higher voltage go to lower voltage) but result is same.

Unfortunately hard to follow. Click on edit and then on the schematic symbol. From there, a schematic drawing tool will open up so you can draw it there. Inputs on the left, outputs on the right, positive voltages on top/pointing up and vice versa for ground and negative.

@winny thanks for the tip ! i didn't know such a feature is available in forum .

Much better! If FS1000A has 9 V Vcc, does it accept 5 V data level? I would assume yes, but devil's in the details.

@winny yes it has input voltage of 5 to 12 . but the problem is it wont work when vcc is not from esp8266 .  if vcc be from esp8266 it works fine with 5 volt too ( at lower power )

@winny datasheet says :
Working voltage: 3V - 12V  fo max. power use 12V
Working current: max  Less than 40mA max , and min 9mA
Resonance mode: (SAW)
Modulation mode: ASK
Working frequency: Eve 315MHz  Or  433MHz
Transmission power: 25mW (315MHz at 12V)
Frequency error: +150kHz (max)
Velocity :  less than 10Kbps

Yes, but with 9 V Vcc, does it accept 5 V data or does it scale to 9 V?

@winnysorry but i don't understand . i dont have much electrician knowledge . i only how to wire up . it is possible to you check it out ?

Link to datasheet? Also, add decoupling capacitors next to each IC between Vcc and GND.

i searched for datasheet but seems there is no datasheet for this transmitter . i found a relative topic and this

No datasheet = no sale.

Chinese manufactures do sale ig .

What we mean is we can't design for stuff that even the seller doesn't know the specs of. Its just guessing and headaches

oh ok get it . thanks anyway

1 - The battery is connected incorrectly.
The positive terminal of the battery should go to the "In" terminals of the regulators.
The negative terminal of the battery should be connected to all GNDs. The way it is depicted on your schematic the battery is not connected at all (only one terminal), so the power you might be getting can be from the USB connection or something similar).
2 - You have a capacitor blocking DC.
It should be in parallel with the load
3 - Regulator output capacitor
Your circuit might (will likely do) work without a capacitor on the output of the regulator (because the modules you are using already have some limited input capacitance). But its good practice (basically necessary) to put bypass capacitors on the output of your regulator (the datasheet will have recommendations on it, i.e.: no MLCCs, capacitance range and so on)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
D1 is kinda optional depending on the regulator you are using and input vs output capacitance, please refer to the datasheet of the part you are using and if you have specific questions come back and we'll help you.
For reference this is OPs schematic:


i get it . battery connection problem is because im not familiar with schematic design and electronic ! in board battery is correctly connected .i will edit my schematic to fix that

please see updated image

Try adding some capacitance as close as possible to the FS1000A power input pins.

thanks . so beside needing capacitor close to fs1000a power inputs , rest of my circuit is ok ? because just i test it and didn't work as i expected . it transmit some data but at its lowest power . like it is off or doing nothing . input vcc of fs1000a is 9 volt which is close to its maximum input ( 12v ) and i expect it to transmit with much more power .

Please update yout post with pictures of your setup, maybe there are some connection issues. Can you confirm that you have 9V on the input of the module? (with a multimeter)

no sry my setup is unavailable right now . but i tested it with multi meter last night and had 9v input . so confirm 9v input .
